# I don't understand a simple electric circuit for a light to work (as explained in allaboutcircuit's eBook)

Tags: power-electronics

Here is my recap:

A semiconductor material will move electrons around; a battery gets the electrons "moving", and they move past a resistor to a coil to light up an LED.

What exactly is the resistor doing? I have read and studied, but this is not clear much to me.

The battery moves the electrons, and they move past the resistor, and the resistor "lights up the LED"? I thought electrons lit the LED? I am confused.

Any short clarification?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either so maybe if you can add a link to what the book is precisely saying this might help

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to find a book on the basics of electricity

The battery provides a force that pushes on charge carriers.

Charge carriers in metal wires are electrons

The electric current is the number of charge carriers flowing past a point per second times the charge carried by each carrier.

The resistor limits the current that can flow. Other wise too much current would flow and burn-out the LED.

The flow of current through the LED causes it to emit light.

The old incandescent light bulbs (glowing coiled wire in a glass bulb) had a low resistance when cold and allowed high currents at start-up but as they heated up to white-hot, their resistance naturally increases. This is why this older type of lamp didn't require a separate resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Electrons do light up the LED.  However, too many electrons can overheat the LED and cause it to fail.  The resistor limits the amount of electrons that the battery can supply the LED.  So the LED gets just enough electrons to light but not too many.

Answer (score 1):

> Any short clarification?

Simply, the LED will be damaged by too much current if it is connected *directly* to the battery.

The resistor effectively keeps the current below a maximum value given by the battery voltage divided by the resistance.

Essentially, the designer determines the value of the current she wants through the LED and then she determines the value of the resistor as follows:

R = (Battery voltage - Nominal LED Voltage) / (Desired LED Current)

In words, the battery voltage minus the LED voltage is the voltage across the resistor.  Since the desired current is known and the voltage across the resistor is known, the value of the resistance can be calculated.